# Uncaught TypeError: doc.autoTable is not a function

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to use the autotable plugin of jspdf to insert a table in a pdf. I tried with a small example and it is working just fine, but when implementing in my webapp it throws me the above error. I'm using cdn to load the plugins.

**Working html**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.5.22/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>


<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.2/dat.gui.js"></script> 
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Working call**
let doc = new jsPDF()

```
doc.addImage(img, 'png', 110, 100, 70, 70)

doc.autoTable({html: '#tbl', theme: 'striped', startY: 190})
```

**Not working html**

```
    <script src="{% static 'leafletPlugins/Edit.Rectangle.Rotate.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'leafletPlugins/leaflet-geoman.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'turf.min.js' %}"></script>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="{% static 'src/jquery-migrate.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="{% static 'FileSaver.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'html2canvas.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.6/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'leaflet-image.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'celery_progress/celery_progress.js' %}"></script>
    

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports":{
                "three": "../static/three/build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "../static/three/examples/jsm/",
                "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls": "../three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
    
    <script type='module' src="{% static 'automaticApproach.js' %}"></script>
```

**Not working call**
let doc = new jsPDF()

```
        doc.addImage(img,'png',110, 100, 70,70)

        doc.autoTable(doc, {html:'#tbl', theme:'striped', startY:190})
```